# How to copy register with DetailView and get pk (Django)

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-shell

Consider my template:

## entry_detail.html

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-right" action="." method="get">
    <!-- add -->
    <!-- <p name="filter_link" class="pull-right"><a href="">Produtos em baixo estoque</a></p> -->
    <a name="new_customer" href="{% url 'proposal_list' %}">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> Criar Orçamento
        </button>
    </a>
</form>
```

And considerer my view:

## views.py

```
class EntryDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'core/entry/entry_detail.html'
    model = Entry

    def create_proposal(self, employee_pk=8):
        if 'new_customer' in self.request.GET:
            employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=employee_pk)
            num_last_proposal = NumLastProposal.objects.get(
                pk=1)  # sempre pk=1
            entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET[self.id])
            obj = Proposal(
                num_prop=num_last_proposal.num_last_prop + 1,
                type_prop='R',
                category=entry.category,
                description=entry.description,
                work=entry.work,
                person=entry.person,
                employee=employee,
                seller=entry.seller,
            )
            obj.save()

            entry.is_entry = True
            entry.save()

            num_last_proposal.num_last_prop += 1
            num_last_proposal.save()
```

**Question**: How to make this work this. How to get entry.pk in DetailView for use in

```
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=self.request.GET[self.id])
```

In manage.py shell its work

## shell_create_proposal.py

```
from core.models import Entry, Proposal, Employee, NumLastProposal

employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=8)
num_last_proposal = NumLastProposal.objects.get(pk=1)
entry = Entry.objects.get(pk=1)
obj = Proposal(
    num_prop=num_last_proposal.num_last_prop + 1,
    type_prop='R',
    category=entry.category,
    description=entry.description,
    work=entry.work,
    person=entry.person,
    employee=employee,
    seller=entry.seller,
)
obj.save()

entry.is_entry = True
entry.save()

num_last_proposal.num_last_prop = num_last_proposal.num_last_prop + 1
num_last_proposal.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the pk in the url and the detail view should handle it for you

```
url(r'^yourview/(?P<pk>\d+)/' , YourDetailView.as_view() , name='your_view_name' ),
```

Look at the get_object method here:

http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.8/django.views.generic.detail/DetailView/

it gets the pk as follows:

```
pk = self.kwargs.get(self.pk_url_kwarg, None)
```

Comment: This I know , the problem is how to get the pk in view to copy the data .

Comment: I updated the answer to show how the get object method does it. You could have looked it up on the page I showed you.